# Invalid target channel.driver error

Tags: animation, rigging

Well I'm quite a newbie in Blender and I'm currently using the Cg cookie baker animation. All of the rigs work, except the facial shape keys won't work with the bones. In the graph editor the drivers show "invalid target channel" although everything is already set up and it still shows even when I click "update dependencies"

[image: invalid target channel[![][1]][1]]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using an old copy of the rig, probably the version that was included with the animation course which was made in v2.56. The new version of baker has changed a little.

Go to the CGCookie resource page and download the [current version of the baker rig](https://cgcookie.com/resource/baker-rig).

[image: baker rig]

Comment: thank you but is there any answer to why the bones for the shape keys are not working?

Comment: My guess is incompatibility between versions. Using the old file, if you add a driver to the shapekey value you will find the path shown in the graph editor is different. blender v2.56 that was used to make it was released in 2010 - 6.5 years ago and it was still considered a beta version release of the then new 2.5x versions. While blender is good at opening older files we can't expect 100% of all data.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem and fixed it by first applying the driver to the armature, selecting the bone, and then changing the *Type* to *Averaged Value* in the driver side toolbar.

If you select the type first, it'll show that error message, but you can just reselect averaged value to fix it, at least for me.